# openmp for block error

Tags: c, openmp

Why does openmp give me this error :-

error: for statement expected before ‘{’ token

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

#pragma omp parallel 
{

int a[100],b[100],c[100];
int i =0;

    for(; i < 100; i++){
    a[i] = i;
    b[i] = i;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,5)
    {
    int i = 0;
        for( ; i < 100 ; i++){ // this is the for loop that is referred in the error message
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }

    }

}

printf("Outside parallel block \n");

}
```

Answer (score 6):

First, the second OpenMP pragma shouldn't have a "parallel" in it; you've already opened a parallel block, you just now need to share the work of the for loop.

Second, you can't have the parallel for enclose a general block; it has to be a for loop.  If you really want a different `i` than is used above, do:

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static,5)
for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
{
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*This is an answer I posted to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807069/openmp-for-statement-expected-before-token) question before I realised it is a duplicate of this one. As it somehow expands on the answers already given here, I'm reposing it.*

`parallel for` is a combined directive. It combines `parallel` and `for` in a single directive, which allows for some space saving.

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(sum) private(i,j,k)
...
```

is basically a shorthand notation for

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(sum) private(i,j,k)
{
   #pragma omp for
   ...
}
```

(the `private` clause could also be attributed to the `for` directive)

Since the syntax of the `for` directive requires that it is **immediately followed** by a `for`-loop, the same syntax requirement applies to the `parallel for` directive. In other words, the `...` above can only be a `for`-loop with its associated (block) body:

```
#pragma omp parallel for ...
for (...)
{
   ...
}
```

Having the `for`-loop inside a block is erroneous. Having the entire parallel region inside a block is not though. The following is a perfectly valid syntax:

```
{
   #pragma omp parallel for ...
   for (...)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do so

```
int i;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,5)
for (i=0;...
```

Comment: I have been thinking about this. My concern is, if 'i' becomes a shared variable for different threads (instead of individual to each thread). Will the result be erratic due to different threads writing on the same variable?

Comment: @julianromera Yes. This answer needs to also state `private(i)` in order to be correct.