# Number of threads with OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp, computer-science

Currently I'm doing a course in parallel computing. I want to run a program with a specific number of threads to check what the difference in execution time will be. I found a similar post helpful, but unfortunately the solution doesn't really help me further.
([OpenMP set_num_threads() is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095309/openmp-set-num-threads-is-not-working))
([openmp for block error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264680/openmp-for-block-error))

The code of my program is:

```
#define SIZE 1000


main ()
{

   float A[SIZE][SIZE], b[SIZE], c[SIZE];
   int i, j, n;
   double fTimeStart, fTimeEnd;

   /* Initializations */
   for (i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
     for (j=0; j < SIZE; j++)
         /* fminf(x,y) gives the minimum of x and y  */
       A[i][j] = fminf(i*1.0/(j+1.0),j*1.0/(i+1.0));
     b[i] = 1.0 * (i+1);
     c[i] = 0.0;
   }

   fTimeStart = omp_get_wtime();


   omp_set_num_threads(4);
   #pragma omp for schedule(static)
   for (i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
       for (j=0; j < SIZE; j++)
           c[j] = c[j] + A[j][i] * b[i];
    printf("threads: %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());


   fTimeEnd = omp_get_wtime();
   printf("  wall clock time     = %.20f\n", fTimeEnd - fTimeStart);
}
```

I assume that the problem is in the parallel region.

```
fTimeStart = omp_get_wtime();


   {
   omp_set_dynamic(0);
   omp_set_num_threads(4);
   #pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (j=0; j < SIZE; j++)
            c[j] = c[j] + A[j][i] * b[i];
    printf("threads: %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
   }


   fTimeEnd = omp_get_wtime();
   printf("  wall clock time     = %.20f\n", fTimeEnd - fTimeStart);
```

The output of the program with regard to the number of threads is 1. That is odd, since I tried to set it to 4.

Question: Why isn't the program executed in 4 threads?

Edit: After to suggestion of @igorR to bring the printstatement in the forloop. I also tried in the outerloop, but after recompiling I only get one print statement and still one thread.

```
   omp_set_dynamic(0);
   omp_set_num_threads(4);
   #pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (j=0; j < SIZE; j++)
            c[j] = c[j] + A[j][i] * b[i];
            n = omp_get_num_threads();
            printf("threads: %d", n);
```

Thanks,
Ter

Comment: What is the output of this program? Why do you think it is not running with 4 threads?

Comment: Hi, the output with regard to the threads is 1. I thought maybe this piece of code is too small to be split in 4 threads.

Comment: But honestly I don't really know, since I would expect 4 threads to be my output

Comment: You print this out of parallel region. Try moving printf into for loop.

Comment: @igorR. Thanks for your reply. I tried to bring the first statement in the for loop. I did it in two ways. In the first loop and in the second loop. I saved an recompiled, but something weird happened. I got one print output, where many were expected and still one thread being used. Please check my edit of the post to see what I changed.

Comment: Run your program in a debugger.  Set a breakpoint inside the for loop.  Inspect the threads (`info threads` in GDB), how many do you see?

Comment: Read your code again. It is not the same as the snippet. The code has no parallelism...

Comment: I found out that the brackets were missing. I works as expected now! Thanks :)

Comment: I encourage you to get in the habit of using curly braces on the body of all your loops and conditionals.  See https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/ for a motivating example.